# What are some effective tools or approaches for writing a stream of Kafka Protobuf messages to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I have a Kafka stream of Protobuf messages that I would like to write to S3 where they can be queried using Athena or similar tools. My clues so far are to convert the Protobuf messages to Parquet and create a table on top of them in Athena, and when adding files just repair the table. Are there any good libraries that do this already? I am not the most experienced in this area and would like to start with a good foundation. My tech stack is the standard JVM (Kotlin, Java, and Scala) languages, along with Spring, Kafka, Parquet, AWS, and S3.

Comment: Have you tried using the S3 Sink Connector?

Comment: It looks like s3 sink connector only supports json and avro.

Comment: ParquetFormat class exists too. Parquet output format should work for Protobuf serialized messages, as well